# Can't use require method in Watson node.js chatbot

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules, watson, watson-conversation

So, I picked up one of the sample chatbots from the watson developer cloud https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud

I was just tweaking it a bit and trying to add more functionalities by using require() methods in node.js. None of them seem to work. I used browserify and made a bundle.js with all dependencies. I made a reference to this scrpt tag in index.html. Still, no success. Dependencies have been mentioned in package.json.

Any alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: You should post your basic code here

Comment: Just to be sure: are aware that node.js modules need to be installed separately? For example, adding require("module-x") will not work unless you do "npm install module-x" or add it to your package.json and run "npm install" on the prompt.